# Why does this upvar refer to the global context? Or can upvar be used in a coroutine?

Tags: tcl, coroutine, upvar

The following strained example, in attempt to match my real situation, completes successfully but not the way I'd like it to; nor do I understand why or can find an answer in one of my books.

I can see that `proc func` was called from the global level and, in turn, initially called `proc cofunc`; and, perhaps, that sets what `upvar` will use. But `proc finalize` calls the coroutine again and passes the variable name `nbr` to `cofunc`--which calls `add`. In this respect `add` "seems" to be two levels from `finalize`.

The `upvar 2 $varName n` in `proc add` is the variable name `nbr` and takes its value from the global variable of that name. I'd like to get it from `proc finalize` (so 15, not 85) which seems to be two levels away from `proc add` but apparently is not even in the list of caller contexts.

I assume `[yield]` is the reason; but would you please explain why and, more importantly, if the value in `proc finalize` was not a number but a "large" value that shouldn't be passed around, is it possible to `upvar` or `uplevel` from a coroutine?

Thank you for considering my question.

```
proc cofunc {callback vals} {
  set var [yield]
  $callback $vals $var
}
proc func {callback vals} {
  set nbr 22
  coroutine coro cofunc $callback $vals
}
proc add {vals varName} {
  upvar 2 $varName n
  chan puts stdout "varName: $varName; n: $n"
  # => varName: nbr; n: 85
  chan puts stdout [expr {[lindex $vals 0]+[lindex $vals 1]+$n}]; 
  # => 115
}
proc finalize {nbr} {
  coro nbr
}

set nbr 85
func add {10 20}
after 500 finalize 15
after 1000 set forever 1
vwait forever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `upvar` (like the `uplevel` command) is defined in terms of the stack. The number argument says how many steps up the stack to take (or you can prefix the number with `#` to count down from the other end; that's a bit less common); it defaults to `1`, the caller of the current procedure. There are two sorts of stack frame, one for procedures (and related entities, such as methods and lambda  expressions) and another for direct namespaces (the global scope, `namespace eval`, and a few other things). All `upvar` does is go to the indicated stack frame, look up the named variable there, and make a local variable that is a link to it. By "link", I mean that the local variable is really a tagged C pointer to the implementation of the other variable. Once a linked variable is set up, access is very fast, as the slow part of access is resolving names to implementations, and local variables are usually compiled into indexed accesses.

The `global` and `namespace upvar` commands do something very similar, but with different lookup strategies. (Also, `global` assumes that the global and local names should match.) That's also *part* of what the `variable` command does.

---

In your code sample, the `upvar 2` is to get past the `cofunc` procedure. I think it would be clearer if it was `upvar #0`, or if `cofunc` used `tailcall $callback` so a simple `upvar` could be used. And I'm pretty sure that the `nbr` accessed in `add` is not the same one as in `func`, as the latter's stack frame will be gone by then.

Comment: Coroutines do not capture the stack at the time they are created. They make a completely new stack.

Comment: Thanks. The `nbr` accessed in `add` is not from `func (22)` it is from `global (85)` but I wanted to get it from `finalize (15)`.  I want a pointer to what the delayed response returns in `finalize` but it doesn't appear to be part of the stack or not available at the time.  I see now that `cofunc` is `upvar 1` and `global` is `upvar 2`. `func` returned after the coroutine was "set up." I suppose `finalize` returned after it called `coro` and is not part of the call stack available to `cofunc`. I need to read more about `return` and the call stack.